# portable __attribute__ ((__packed__))

Tags: c++, c, portability

Is there a portable equivalent of  `__attribute__ ((__packed__))`

(by portability I mean working on PC, Android and iPhones, regardless architecture)

Comment: @bmargulies: actually, `alignas` in c++11 makes that less simple

Comment: Oh, well. I left it as a comment because I was afraid of something like that.

Comment: I thought `#pragma pack` was supported on both Visual Studio and recent GCC.  That may or may not be good enough for your use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, `__attribute__`s are non-portable. If you want your data a specific way, the Plan9 solution is usually to use `unsigned char` arrays in your structure:

```
struct foo {
    uchar data1[4];
    uchar other[2];
}
```

Usually won't have any alignment, since it's fundamentally using unsigned characters. Of course, if you have a high tolerance for pain, you could always use an `enum` of offsets:

```
enum { FOO_DATA1=0, FOO_OTHER=4, FOO_LAST=6 };
```

You could then load it up like so:

```
unsigned char foo[FOO_LAST];
uint32_t n = htonl(val)
memcpy(foo+FOO_DATA1, &n, sizeof n)
memcpy(foo+FOO_OTHER, &some_16_bit_val, sizeof some_16_bit_val)
```

As long as you have the stomach for it, it will be completely portable.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually aiming for the first solution. I didn't know its specific to Plan9

Answer (score 1):

No.  Structure packing and padding is not part of the C++ language specification (it belongs to the platform ABI), so anything that deals with it is inherently outside the language.

Comment: Even alignment does relates to platform ABI and now it's part of the standard. Packing is another stuff that is out of the standard with poor reasons and compiler developers are basically forced to add non standard extensions to provide it.